# Build software on Linux using cross toolchain

Tags: compilation, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, toolchain

Motorola provides a cross compiling toolchain for building Software for their Set Top Box VIP1710. You have to extract it to `/usr/local/kreatel` and there you have a tree of build tools:

```
./bin
./bin/mipsel-kreatel-linux-gnu-addr2line
./bin/mipsel-kreatel-linux-gnu-ar
./bin/mipsel-kreatel-linux-gnu-as
./bin/mipsel-kreatel-linux-gnu-c++
./bin/mipsel-kreatel-linux-gnu-c++filt
./bin/mipsel-kreatel-linux-gnu-cpp
./bin/mipsel-kreatel-linux-gnu-g++
./bin/mipsel-kreatel-linux-gnu-gcc
...
./include
./lib
```

Now how do I make those `configure` scripts using my cross-compiling tools instead of my systems' gcc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `--host` parameter to configure, like this

```
./configure --host=arm-9tdmi-linux-gnu
```

where arm-9tdmi-linux-gnu is the identfication of the target system in my case - you can have multiple targets in one crosstool installation btw.

Comment: But as the toolchain is in /usr/local/kreatel/..., `configure` says: `checking for mipsel-kreatel-linux-gnu-gcc... no`

Comment: @flo prepend the bin directory of your crosstool to the path, like this PATH=/usr/local/kreatel/bin:$PATH